# How to reduce a frame size on clicking a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Actually I'm using the frames in order to segment an entire window.So,I've used four html pages over here.

Here I've segmented all the frames in test.html.I've drop down box in bottom.html.If we click on the drop down box the frame size should be expanded and later we can select the options in that list.If no option is selected,then we should reduce the frame size.

For reference of this requirement you can see in this url:[Reference](http://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=e9krd11m38onf_&ctype=m&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=s&met_s=number_of_tests&scale_s=lin&ind_s=false&met_c=download_throughput&scale_c=lin&ind_c=false&ifdim=country&hl=en_US&dl=en_US&ind=false&xMax=180&xMin=-180&yMax=-79.97571094413946&yMin=84.17339026552769&mapType=t&icfg&iconSize=0.5#!ctype=m&strail=false&bcs=d&nselm=s&met_s=number_of_tests&scale_s=lin&ind_s=false&met_c=receiver_limited&scale_c=lin&ind_c=false&ifdim=country&hl=en_US&dl=en_US&ind=false)

My test.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.expanded {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$("input[type='checkbox'").click( function() {

  if($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0) {
    $("frame[name='bottom_page']").addClass("expanded");

  } else {
    $("frame[name='bottom_page']").removeClass("expanded");
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<frameset cols="30%,100%">
  <frameset rows="70,200">
  <frame src="top.html" name="top_page" />
  <frame src="bottom.html" name="bottom_page" />
</frameset>
<frame src="main.html" name="main_page" />
</frameset>

</html>
```

My bottom.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .multiselect {
                width: 200px;
            }
            .selectBox {
                position: relative;
            }
            .selectBox select {
                width: 100%;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .overSelect {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;
            }
            #checkboxes {
                display: none;
                border: 1px #dadada solid;
            }
            #checkboxes label {
                display: block;
            }
            #checkboxes label:hover {
                background-color: #1e90ff;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#B5DCB3">

        <script>
         var expanded = false;
            function showCheckboxes() {
                var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
                if (!expanded) {
                    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
                    expanded = true;
                } else {
                    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
                    expanded = false;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <form>
            <div class="multiselect">
                <div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes()" >
                    <select>
                        <option>Select Country</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="overSelect" id="selectId"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="checkboxes">
                    <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" id="one"/>Afghanistan</label>
                    <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" id="two"/>Aland Islands</label>
                    <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" id="three"/>Albania</label>
                    <label for="four"><input type="checkbox" id="four"/>Algeria</label>
                    <label for="five"><input type="checkbox" id="five"/>American Samoa</label>
                    <label for="six"><input type="checkbox" id="six"/>Andorra</label>
                    <label for="seven"><input type="checkbox" id="seven"/>Angola</label>
                    <label for="eight"><input type="checkbox" id="eight"/>Anguilla</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please suggest me regarding this issue...

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, this may be a suitable solution:

```
// Watch for checkbox selection changes
$("input[type='checkbox'").click( function() {
  // If more than one checkbox is selected, add expanded class to target
  if($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0) {
    $("frame[name='main_page']").addClass("expanded");
  // If not, remove expanded class
  } else {
    $("frame[name='main_page']").removeClass("expanded");
  }
});
```

Here's [a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrodie/2wssabuz/) of it in action.

Comment: Should I write this code in bottom.html page ? Actually frames are in test,html page and the checkbox is in bottom.html page.How can we use bottom.html code in test.html ?

Comment: So to clarify, you want an event to occur in one frame with another frame changing based on this event?

Comment: Currently I'm trying to keep the "bottom_page"  frame size  flexible based on drop down box selections .You can see this requirement in the above mentioned url.Can u put the working code in JSFiddle regarding the frame size.

Comment: The above code works if you have the checkbox elements within `test.html`.